# setAttribute no está definido

Tags: javascript, html

Estoy tratando de añadir un atributo a un elemento del `DOM` con `js`

El elemento al que estoy intentando asignar el atributo no tiene `id` y no tengo forma de añadirle uno, ya que trabajo con prestashop

Estoy intentando hacerlo con `getElementsByClassName` de la siguiente forma pero me da el siguiente error

**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setAttribute' of undefined**

El código `js` está alojado en un archivo independiente y no el `DOM`.

```js
var cartDescription = document.getElementsByClassName("cart_description")[0];
cartDescription.setAttribute("colspan","2");
```

```html
<table>
<th class="cart_description item">Descripción</th>
</table>
```

Comment: El ejemplo que proporcionas en la pregunta funcionan perfectamente. ¿Estas seguro que cuando haces `getElementsByClassName` el elemento existe?

Comment: Es posible que no exista un elemento, probá haciendo un `console.log(document.getElementsByClassName("cart_description"))` y fijate si te devuelve resultado. El seteo del atributo está bien, no hay error ahí.

Comment: Al estar el js en otro archivo, igual hay que meterlo en una funcion y llamarlo desde el DOM?

Comment: No, pero depende si también se crea dinámicamente esa tabla (con javascript), entonces no lo va a encontrar. Una posible solución es poner el llamado de ese archivo `.js` al final, justo antes del cierre del `</body>`.